# How to make an output in respective li-tag?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a code that if you check the checkbox, the zero will become one, then if you uncheck, the one will become zero. In short, I make an output in every `onchange event` that it prints only `0` and `1` where `0` is `false` statement and `1` is `true` tatement.

Despite for that, I created a `setInterval` function to make a function that when the status is `1`, then it display the word "Active", else, the word "Active" will be gone.

Below is my code and working perfectly but the only problem is the code is longer and it becomes longer if I added an element or array. Like for example if I add 10 countries.

I don't know how to manage that code to make it shorter because I new to this kind of project to my website. Is there's a possibility make it shorter? Please Help me.

```js
const Countries = ["Philippines", "New York", "Singapore"];

function createList() {
  const liTag = $('.Handler');
  for (let i = 0; i < Countries.length; i++) {
    const List = `
<ul id="CountryList">
<li>
    <div class="NameOfCountry">
<input type="checkbox" class="Check">
<p class="CountryName">Hello</p>
<p class="status">0</p>
<p class="IfActive">Active</p>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>   
`;
    var elem = $(List);
    elem.find('.CountryName').html(Countries[i]);
    elem.find('.Check').change(function() {

    })
    liTag.append(elem);

  }
}
createList();

document.querySelectorAll('.Check').forEach(check => {
  check.addEventListener('change', ({
    target
  }) => {
    const {
      parentNode,
      checked
    } = target
    const inActiveElement = parentNode.querySelector('.status')
    inActiveElement.innerText = checked ? '1' : '0'
  })
})

setInterval(function() {
  PLC.click();
}, 1);

function Stat() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("status");
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName("IfActive");
  /* IS THERE'S A POSSIBILITY TO SHORTER THIS CODE?*/
  if (x[0].innerHTML == "0") {
    y[0].style.display = "none";
  }
  if (x[0].innerHTML == "1") {
    y[0].style.display = "block";
  }

  if (x[1].innerHTML == "0") {
    y[1].style.display = "none";
  }
  if (x[1].innerHTML == "1") {
    y[1].style.display = "block";
  }

  if (x[2].innerHTML == "0") {
    y[2].style.display = "none";
  }
  if (x[2].innerHTML == "1") {
    y[2].style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
/*
This is commented out, because without a leading selector and missing
an opening "{" character this is simply a syntax error, and Stack
Overflow policy is to avoid correcting code in the question as that -
in many cases - disguises the original problem, or invalidates
existing answers. Obviously OP is welcome to correct the code (either
by themselves or via comments on the question for someone else to
follow:

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
*/

body {
  background: #40fff5;
}

.Handler {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.NameOfCountry {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.CountryName {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.IfActive {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.status {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="Handler"></div>
<button class="hidden" onclick="Stat()" id="PLC">CLICK ME</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

PS: I used mobile phone for now so that the Code Snippet is not available, if someone edit my code to make it available on Code Snippet then it so much appreciated for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the same way as how you change the 0 <-> 1 with: `parentNode.querySelector('.IfActive').style.display = checked ? 'block' : 'none';`

This way you can get rid of the interval and hidden button which makes your code more complex then necessary.

**Note:** You seems to be using both native Javascript and jQuery. I would recommend to go for either 1 or the other to make your code more consistent and readable. Since you using a really old version of jQuery too you might want to upgrade that too if you want to keep using it.

```js
const Countries = ["Philippines", "New York", "Singapore"];

function createList() {
  const liTag = $('.Handler');
  for (let i = 0; i < Countries.length; i++) {
    const List = `
    <ul id="CountryList">
      <li>
          <div class="NameOfCountry">
            <input type="checkbox" class="Check">
            <p class="CountryName">Hello</p>
            <p class="status">0</p>
            <p class="IfActive">Active</p>
          </div>
      </li>
    </ul>`;
    var elem = $(List);
    elem.find('.CountryName').html(Countries[i]);
    liTag.append(elem);
  }
}

createList();

document.querySelectorAll('.Check').forEach(check => {
  check.addEventListener('change', ({target}) => {
    const {parentNode, checked } = target;
    const inActiveElement = parentNode.querySelector('.status');
    inActiveElement.innerText = checked ? '1' : '0';

    parentNode.querySelector('.IfActive').style.display = checked ? 'block' : 'none';
  });
});
```

```css
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
outline: none;
box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  background: #40fff5;
}
.Handler {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
.NameOfCountry {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
.CountryName {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.IfActive {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
.status {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="Handler"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello there, I don't want it. Because I want the output 0 and 1 will be stored in storage using ```localStorage.set()``` so that if the website is refreshed, the code or output will be back.

Comment: Like for example if I check the first element, the outut will be 1-0-0 then that output will stored in localStorage, after refreshing the website, the 1-0-0 will be get back and make a code that if the element has a status of 1, then it display the "Active" Word

Comment: But everything should be in sync? Like when the local storage is set to 0/1 you also want the checkbox to be selected and the active element to be shown (when it's 1). So you can set it all at once. Abusing the interval for that is horrible design in my opinion.

Comment: No, how you display the "Active" Word when the status print "1"  without setting Interval?

Comment: Setting Interval is important, because even you didn't create any action on page, setting Interval is the only way to help. That if the status is 1, then the word will be **automatically** display. So now, without setting Interval, how you display automatically the word "Active" if the status becomes 1 without making any actions? The ```localStorage.get()``` is the only eay to get the data what you set before. Then after getting the data, it execute the code when the data it get for the status is 1, then the Active Word will displayed **automatically**

Comment: At the same moment you get the value of 0/1 you can set all the properties accordingly. Using the interval is not needed at all and can even cause performance issues if the code gets to complex since you execute it every millisecond. If you can provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a local storage example (by editing your question) I can update my answer accordingly to that.